# Mean curvature flow vs. diffusion

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, heat-equation, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

Mean curvature flow (MCF) and diffusion-type flows both have smoothing effects on a curve.

I can tell there is a deep connection between the two, as seen in the [Merriman-Bence-Osher (MBO)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00205-018-01340-x) numerical scheme, which uses diffusion to approximate MCF: it takes a characteristic function of a region $\Omega$ and iterates the following

1. apply the heat kernel (i.e. allow the boundary to diffuse), and
2. threshold (to recreate a sharp boundary).

What is the relationship between MCF and diffusive flows and how can one explain this geometrically? Honestly I'm not even sure whether "diffusive flow" is a term, but by that I mean evolution of a curve as described by the heat equation/heat kernel.

Edit: I also read somewhere that Ricci flow on a surface effectively evolves the curvature of the surface with a heat equation. Now, how does Ricci flow come into the picture?

Answer (score 2):

So the best reference for this would probably be Merriman, Bence, and Osher's [original paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C47&q=diffusion%20generated%20motion%20by%20mean%20curvature%20merriman%20bence%20osher&btnG=). In it, they show that the heat equation is *locally* a mean curvature flow with rate $D\kappa$.

Specifically, consider a region $\Omega$ and its characteristic function $\chi_\Omega$ (let's just call it $\chi$). We can consider the result of a diffusion of $\chi$, and in particular the effect of the diffusion at a point $P$ on the boundary of $\chi$.

The diffusion equation applied to $\chi$ would be $$ \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t} = D\Delta \chi.$$

Consider the tangent circle to $P$, i.e. if $P$ has local curvature $\kappa = \frac{1}{r}$, the circle with radius $r$.

[image: The image in MBO's paper:]

What is the effect of the diffusion at this point? Rewrite the diffusion equation in the polar coordinates based on the tangent circle to $P$, and we get
$$ \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t} = \frac{D}{r} \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial r} + D\frac{\partial^2 \chi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{D}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \chi}{\partial \theta^2}$$

(note this is the diffusion equation LOCAL to the point $P$).

Since $\chi$ is tangent to the circle at $P$, the curve $\chi$ has locally unchanging angle at $P$, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2 \chi}{\partial \theta^2} = 0$.

Thus the diffusion equation at $P$ becomes
$$ \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t} = \frac{D}{r} \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial r} + D\frac{\partial^2 \chi}{\partial r^2} $$

This is an advection-diffusion equation: the term $D\frac{\partial^2 \chi}{\partial r^2}$  acts to diffuse the the boundary of $\chi$, i.e. smoothing the sharp step that the characteristic function has. The term $\frac{D}{r} \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial r}$is the velocity term, which moves the point $P$ (and all points around it) at speed $\frac{D}{r}$. Since the local curvature at $P$ is $\kappa = \frac{1}{r}$, we have that the local change at $P$ simultaneously

1. diffuses out/spreads
2. moves in the direction of its local curvature with rate $D\kappa$.

This is why the MBO scheme alternates diffusion term and thresholding term. The diffusion term takes a MCF step, but the boundary gets diffuse. The thresholding term resharpens the boundary by defining it to be the level set $\chi = \frac{1}{2}$ (which evolves via MCF since it moves exactly with the advective velocity $D\kappa$).

**TLDR** the diffusion equation applied to the characteristic function $\chi_\Omega$ of a set $\Omega$ causes the boundary $\partial \Omega$ to move according to a mean curvature flow in a small time step, with rate $D\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the curvature at each point. It only works in a small time step because this analysis relies on local polar coordinates at each point on the boundary.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how the boundary "moves"? For heat equation and $t >0$, the function is already everywhere positive. What is the "boundary" when $t >0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $\chi$ is not everywhere positive, it's the characteristic function of $\Omega$. We are repeatedly 1) diffusing it in a small time step and then 2) defining $\Omega(t)$ to be the level set of $\chi = 1/2$. So the overall effect is that we can think of the boundary as $\partial \Omega(t)$ ... is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ah okay, now I just saw the $1/2$ level set in your answer. But this is not really a surprising fact? The MCF equation is locally  $u_t = \frac{u''}{1+(u')^2}$, if you linearize you get the heat equation.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, that would have sufficed as an answer to my original question! Now would you know what the relation to Ricci flow is? (I asked a question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059121/ricci-flow-as-heat-flow-on-riemannian-manifold)

Comment: @900edges This seems to make sense. For some given set, diffusion would just be normal to the boundary at some constant rate $D$. Seems like mean curvature flow just allows $D$ to vary at each point proportional the the curvature at that point. So each point is basically diffusing at different rates. Is that the gist or am I mistaken somewhere.

Comment: @900edges Sorry for this late comment. I am a bit lost when you said "The thresholding term resharpens the boundary by defining it to be the level set $\chi = \frac{1}{2}$ (which evolves via MCF since it moves exactly with the advective velocity $D\kappa$)". If $\chi$ is the characteristic function of some set $\Omega$, $\chi$ can only take values $0$ or $1$ right?

Comment: @FeiCao Yes! I included a community wiki post with a graphic that hopefully makes sense.

Comment: @900edges sorry maybe my question is not that clear. I am wondering why the $\frac 12$ suddenly pops up. If you look at the origin paper *"Diffusion generated motion by mean curvature"*, they mentioned that "this level moves exactly with the advective velocity". what does this mean? Also, I am wondering whether there is a source code for implementing the algorithm in page 5 of that paper. Thank you!

Comment: @ArcticChar If you don't mind, can you explain why the $\frac 12$ suddenly pops up? I have no clue where it is coming from...

Comment: @FeiCao I'm guessing any constant between 0 and 1 would work (maybe needing a rescaling of the velocity), but there might be a theoretical justification somewhere in there

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First: heat flow step smooths the functional.

Second: threshold step redefines the functional to be the indicator function of the 1/2-level set.